# How to put borders in panels background like outlook day view, when the panel is sizable?

Tags: wpf

I'm talking WPF...
I have a panel (with virtualization). The panel has a custom measure and arrange implementation.
I want the panel background to look like Outlook calendar in the day view (with the lines for each amount of time) any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to override the panel's OnRender and draw the lines (or place a new custom control behind the panel that will draw the lines).

Comment: do you have a sample? i how do i draw this lines?

Comment: @Chen Kinnrot - you already override MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride, so you can also override OnRender, OnRender gets a DrawingContext as a parameter and the DrawinContext has all sort of useful methods like DrawLine and DrawText you can use to create the outlook-like background